# Best way to build a cmake static library from a parent cmake dynamic/static library

Tags: cmake, static-libraries

I would like to add this cmake-based static library

https://github.com/google/highway

to my static or dynamic library

https://github.com/GrokImageCompression/grok

So, I would like to build static library first, then build the dynamic library
and link to the static library.

I have added the static library as a subfolder, and the .a file is being generated in my
cmake binary folder. But, I am not sure how to link to this library

`target_link_libraries(${PARENT_LIBRARY_NAME} ${PARENT_BIN_DIR}/hwy)`

doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the name of the target in the call to `target_link_libraries`, i.e. `target_link_libraries(${PARENT_LIBRARY_NAME} PUBLIC hwy)` or `target_link_libraries(${PARENT_LIBRARY_NAME} PRIVATE hwy)` depending on whether you make use of `hwy`s headers in public headers of the parent library (choose PUBLIC) or only in the implementation of the parent library (choose PRIVATE).

Comment: Thank you very much !!